Is the family of pseudometrics defining the topology of a TVS always equivalent to a translation-invariant family?
Rudin's Functional analysis Theorem 1.24 states, for a metrizable TVS, there always exists a translation-invariant metric matching the topology. But since every TVS, not necessarily Hausdorff, is uniformizable and its topology can be induced by a family of pseudometrics, can I apply Rudin's theorem and conclude the toplogy is actually always induced by a family of translation-invariant pseudometrics?
I can't see why it can't be true, since, if the original family is $\{d_i\}$ and the subbase of uniformity are sets of the form $d_i^{-1}([0,1/n))$, then for every $d_i$, just apply the theorem and get a translation-invariant $d_i'$, then all the sets ${d_i'}^{-1}([0,1/n))$ is another subbase of uniformity (right?). Is there anything wrong with this argument? Thanks in advance.
PS: Even if this is true, unless the cardinality of this family can be reduced to $1$, the TVS is not an F-space. Also, unless each translation-invariant pseudometric is homogeneous, it is not a LCS.

@QiaochuYuan With the same vector space $X$, each $d_i$ induces a pseudometric topology, which is coarser than the original topology. With this pseudometric topology, what is wrong with applying Rudin's theorem, and get a translation-invariant $d_i'$? Sorry if this is something silly and obvious that I can't see yet

Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. Well, now I really don't know.

The problem with your argument is that the topology induced by one of the pseudometrics $d_i$ need not be a vector space topology so that you can't apply the theorem from Rudin.

@Jochen That's indeed true. However, it's not a genuine obstacle for that conclusion to be true.

I know. You might be interested in the book of Adasch, Ernst, and Keim which is freely available.

@Jochen Thanks! That's so concise! Anyway I'm not too fond of anything related to taking differentiation. Sometimes always referring back to L^p spaces is also too concrete for my taste. So that's exactly what I like!

I am quite sure the answer is YES.
For a TVS (not necessarily Hausdorff) $X$, every neighborhood of the origin $U$ contains a balanced neighborhood of the origin $V$ s.t. $V+V\subset U$. Therefore, sets
$$W_U:=\{(x,y)\in X\times X: x-y\in U \}$$
form a uniformity $\mathcal{W}$ which is compatible with the topology of $X$. Since for every $z\in X$
$$(x+z,y+z)\in W_U\Leftrightarrow (x,y)\in W_U,$$
uniformity $\mathcal{W}$ is therefore translation-invariant.
Then, for every countable chain of balanced neigborhoods of the origin $U_1\supset U_2\supset \cdots \supset U_n\supset \cdots$ s.t. $U_{n+1}+ U_{n+1}+ U_{n+1}\subset U_n$, the corresponding chain of entourages satisfies $W_{n+1}\circ W_{n+1}\circ W_{n+1}\subset W_n$. By a key lemma of Alexandroff and Urysohn (See Kelley's General Topology Lemma 6.12), such a chain of entourages gives rise to a pseudometric, which is clearly translation-invariant due to how it is defined in the lemma. Since every balanced neighborhood of the origin is contained in such a countable chain, and all the balanced nbhds form a local basis, the collection of all such translation-invariant pseudometrics generates the topology of $X$.
For completeness, I put the lemma here.

Let $X$ be a set and $\{W_n\subset X\times X:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a sequence of symmetric relations s.t. $W_0=X\times X$, and $\Delta\subset W_{n+1}\subset W_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $\Delta:=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$ is the diagonal.

For every $(x,y)\in X\times X$, and every finite composition of relations containing the pair  $\prod_{j=1}^{k}W_{i_j}\ni (x,y)$, where $k\geq 1$, define
$$f\left((x,y);\prod_{j=1}^{k}W_{i_j}\right):=\frac{1}{2^{i_1+1}}+\cdots+ \frac{1}{2^{i_k+1}}.$$
Then function $d(x,y):=\inf\left\{f\left((x,y);\prod_{j=1}^{k}W_{i_j}\right):\prod_{j=1}^{k}W_{i_j}\ni (x,y)\right\}$
is a pseudometric;
If, for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we further have $W_{n+1}\circ W_{n+1}\circ W_{n+1}\subset W_n$, then the pseudometric $d$ also satisfies $W_n\subset\{(x,y):d(x,y)<2^{-n}\}\subset W_{n-1}$.


Note, in our context, $(x,y)\in \prod_{j=1}^{k}W_{i_j}$ if an only if $(x+z,y+z)\in \prod_{j=1}^{k}W_{i_j}$, since all the $W$'s are translation-invariant. So function $f$ defined in the lemma is translation-invariant, and so is pseudometric $d$.
